# using sed to replace string with special characters

Tags: sed

I'm basically trying to modify tomcat server.xml connector tag and add a address attribute to it.

I want to find the below string in server.xml

I'm doing the below with sed,

```
export currlistener=\<Connector\ port\=\"18443\"
export newlistener=\<Connector\ port\=\"18443\"\ address\=\"127.0.0.1\"\
echo $currlistener
echo $newlistener
sed -i -e 's/'$currlistener'/'$newlistener'/g' server.xml
```

But I get the error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unterminated `s' command
```

I guess sed is interpreting the special characters and erroring out.

How would I do the same using awk?

Regards,
Anand.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using sed

The problem was that the shell variables were unquoted.  Try:

```
sed -i -e "s/$currlistener/$newlistener/g" server.xml
```

#### Using awk

The sed solution requires that you trust the source of your shell variables.  For a case like this, awk is safer.  Using a modern GNU awk:

```
awk -i inplace -v a="$currlistener" -v b="$newlistener" '{gsub(a, b)} 1' server.xml
```

Or, using other awk:

```
awk -v a="$currlistener" -v b="$newlistener" '{gsub(a, b)} 1' server.xml >tmp && mv tmp server.sml
```

#### Simplifying the variable assignments

Separately, the shell variables can be defined without requiring so many escapes:

```
currlistener='<Connector port="18443"'
newlistener='<Connector port="18443" address="127.0.0.1"'
```

It is only necessary to export them if they are to be used in a child process.